# How do I access a Facebook users details with their login credentials?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, asp.net-2.0

I have a site where users can register an account. To do this they have to enter various details about themselves (Name, DOB, Email Address, Password, Username etc..).

However, I would like them to just have to enter their Facebook username/password, and have all this information pulled from their Facebook user account.

How is this possible using ASP.NET 2.0?

Thanks!

Curt

Comment: I seriously hope that no facebook user will give their credentials away like this..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're approaching this the wrong way. You should never ask a user for their facebook (or whatever 3rd party) password.
Instead, you can use Facebook Connect to redirect them to Facebook, where they can allow your application, so you will get user info relevant to your site (name, DOB, Email, but not username/password).

I suggest reading the [FB docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web) to get a better idea about the process.

Comment: Thanks Jasper, I'm looking into Facebook Connect now and it seems to make a lot more sense from a security point of view. Cheers.